# Webapi AuthorizeAttribute is not allowing me to access methode when its giving Status message as 200

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

Here i wrote small Authentication as

```
public override void OnAuthorization
  (System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var  authenticationTokenPersistant = "abc";
    base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization") != null)
    {
      string authenticationToken = Convert.ToString(
           actionContext.Request.Headers
             .GetValues("Authorization").FirstOrDefault());
      authenticationTokenPersistant = authenticationToken;
      if (authenticationTokenPersistant == authenticationToken)
      {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Authorization", authenticationToken);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("AuthenticationStatus", "NotAuthorized");
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return;
      }
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Authorization", authenticationToken);
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("AuthenticationStatus", "Authorized");
      return;
    }
    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                             .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
    actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Please provide valid inputs";
}
```

this function i decorated CustomAuthorize its Executing my function but allowing me to Enter inside ValidateSession()

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public IHttpActionResult ValidateSesion()
{
    return ok("Success..");
}
```

when i get 200 Response Even though im getting going inside

Comment: Can you debug the method? Which branch of the `if` statements in your code is used? One thing that I'd suspect could be a problem would be the `CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)` that already sets the response to OK (200). Maybe an else is better suited?

Comment: I think you want to create a class that inherits from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute. There you should override IsAuthorized method and HandleUnauthorizedRequest for returning correct response in case of 'unauthorized'

Comment: @Verthosa yes ur R8